# Can we get a Stack Exchange sandbox?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-exchange, moderators, sandbox

Everyone has always wondered what it's like to be a diamond mod. With The Teams help we can fulfill that dream!

**Proposal:**

One empty stackexchange with a special option set so that every new user is instantly promoted to a diamond moderator

**Solutions:**

No longer will people have to try and guess or bother real moderators with what is possible and not possible for diamond mods. Also, how cool would it be to be capable of banning yourself!

**Etc:**

How about it Jeff? Can we get a blank stack exchange to test things with? Along with being able to have fun with diamond moderator abilities, it'd let everyone be able to test things with the tag wiki and tags and questions, instead of putting fake stuff here on meta. Let **the community** be your testers for every part of your system :)

(*oh please oh please oh please!!!*)

Comment: You know what would be really cool? If you wanted to test some technical specifics or race conditions on posts you could write _scripts_ in the posts that tell the Community user to e.g. “downvote this question once in one minute”, etc. I’d like to see what happens when I’m a 51-rep user, about to post a comment, and _right before_ submitting it, my commenting privilege is revoked due to one downvote. Am I still able to post the comment?

Comment: This is a site proposal and therefore should be on [area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 7):

I'm confused on how this can be useful.

Being a diamond mod TMK doesn't give you many more powers than a 10k. The only new powers that I'm aware of are 100% weight when voting to close/open/move questions, locking questions, and banning users. None of those powers can teach anybody anything. Honestly, an FAQ question would suffice.

All I can see resulting from this is abuse. MSO has a formatting sandbox for... formatting, and question tests are posted so infrequently that a new site would be unnecessary.

Comment: the thing I'm more interested in is instant 10K powers as well as the ability to change things such as tag wikis

Comment: Abuse potential can be mitigated by resetting the site periodically.

Comment: Sorry to rekindle, but this could be useful for testing bus in the site's deep infrastructure, such as [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143907/suggested-edits-to-ones-posts-cannot-be-approved-with-edit-link-if-reveiver-h) (Disclaimer: Self-promotion)

Comment: I am going to introduce one of the stack exchanges to my students this summer semester. However, my first attempt was just plain awful. The student asked a beginner style question and was immediately downvoted and told to go ask his teacher. So I need a sandbox where students can type "Hello World".