# Suggested edits to one's posts cannot be approved with [Edit] link if reviewer has less than 2K rep

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, review

How to confirm:

1. Submit an edit suggestion on a post by a user with less than 2K reputation, using a user with less than 2K reputation.
2. Sign is as the user receiving the edit suggestion and click the [Edit (1)] link below the post.
3. Observe error message denying the user to approve or reject the edit.
4. Observe how the edit can be acted upon via the link from receiver's notifications/inbox.

This first arose here, on [one of my questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143894/edit-feature-has-misaligned-process-tips-suggestions-sidebar), and was deliberately replicated to test on Ask Ubuntu with an anonymous edit to a post with a 1000-odd rep user.

Comment: I just ran into this on LEGO Answers with [this suggested edit](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/218).

Comment: Sorry about that, we'll get this case fixed up.

Comment: @Emmett No problem.

Comment: @Emmett Bugs like there, that can't be tested with just an example post, that need an entire site as a sandbox, are reason to get such a sandbox site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was an oversight by me as we designed the new review dashboard: I didn't account for allowing post *owners* to always be able to approve/reject suggested edits, regardless of their reputation. It's fixed now.

Comment: The owner of the post can approve/reject the edit, even if they have less than 2k rep? I didn't know that. Thanks!